# Add internal webhook on Openshift when creating a new project or namespace

Tags: openshift, webhooks

I'm not talking about creating a webhook from git/gitlab/argocd, what I want is when Openshift will create a new-project, it will call a webhook (or script or procedure), so it's execute only once.  It should create the shared secrets/configmaps.

This should have been the solution, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1346209 but Redhat closed it.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom controller or operator that watch the new-project event, then create a webhook with rate limit, here's a webhook with rate limit, https://github.com/rv-openshift/webhook-rate.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a webhook for this, ie modify the objects created for new projects

You can modify the template used to create new projects and add whatever object you like (ConfigMap etc) and also set security

OCP official doc on this: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/applications/projects/configuring-project-creation.html

The default template create 2 things: a`Project`and a`RoleBinding`